# Is there a clear reason this loop will not vectorize?

Tags: fortran, vectorization, intel, intel-fortran

I am assessing the performance of a Fortran 90 code.  Running the code through Intel's Advisor program I see that loops with the following style are not getting vectorized.  An example of the loop structure is shown in the Subroutine and module files described below.

The code is being compiled with Intel's Compiler 19.0.3
-O3 optimization turned on

```
Subroutine SampleProblem

Use GlobalVariables
Implicit None

Integer :: ND, K, LP, L
Real :: AVTMP

! Sample of loop structure that is no vectorized
DO ND=1,NDM
    DO K=1,KS  
        DO LP=1,LLWET(K,ND)
            L = LKWET(LP,K,ND)  
            AVTMP = AVMX*HPI(L)           
        ENDDO  
    ENDDO  
ENDDO

End Subroutine SampleProblem
```

LLWET and LKWET are allocatable arrays declared in a module 'GlobalVariables'.  Something like:

```
Module GlobalVariables

   Implicit None

   ! Variable declarations
   REAL :: AVMX
   INTEGER :: NDM
   REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:)     :: HPI
   INTEGER,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:,:)   :: LLWET  
   INTEGER,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:,:,:) :: LKWET   

End Module GlobalVariables
```

I don't see why this loop would not get vectorized by the compiler. There are many loops like his all over the code and none of them get vectorized, per the reported results of Intel's Advisor.  I have tried forcing vecotoriztion with a !$SIMD block around the loop.

Comment: And what happened when you tried the simd?

Comment: It might be a win to vectorize it with a gather load for the `L=...` / `HPI(L)` if tuning for Broadwell or especially Skylake.  (But maybe not Haswell with its slow `vgatherdps`).  Maybe set your compiler's tuning options with `-march=skylake`, if ifort takes the same options as icc.

Comment: Of course, the whole loop can optimize except for the very last iteration that sets AVTMP to its final value.

Comment: (I mean optimize *away*).  So if that happens, an optimization-report might show it as not vectorized.

Comment: Yes, I was staring at this wondering why the loop needed doing - Zander, is this really all these loops are doing?